# UWP appx upload to windows store gives market error

Tags: windows, uwp, appx

I am uploading a new appxupload package to the Windows Store and it gives me the error: "You must upload at least one package for each of your market groups."

The package was created using the Desktop Bridge for an older Win32 app.

What does that mean? What is a market group? How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to be able ask better suitable question for this platform.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens while the package is validating. If you wait about 30 minutes and come back the package will have finished uploading and will no longer give this error message.

Otherwise you can also go into the packaging section and review which markets are selected and make sure you have at least 1 market selected and that the packaging setup is marked as completed.