# Getting error while publishing UWP-Xamarin based app on Windows Store

Tags: windows, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

When I try to pubish my UWP Xamarin.Forms based application than it works fine on local machine but when I try to publish it on Microsoft store it gives me below error.

`You must upload at least one package. If you are using market groups, then each market group must have at least one package.`

I try with bundle package(.appxbundle) and also try with (.appx) file but in both time it gives me same error that I mentioned above.

I also try to pubish directly from the visual studio 2017 but when I check browser after update it shows me same error.

I also mention screenshot for better understanding.[image: Put image for understanding better]

Can anyone have idea about this? Please guide.

Comment: Have you checked this link? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143954/uwp-appx-upload-to-windows-store-gives-market-error

Comment: @AdamMcMahon Yes, I check that link and also wait for approx 45min but same error is but there is no progress in upload.

Comment: Are you using a corporate network? If it's a corporate network, is there a limit on that? Could you try another network to do this?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT Thanks for reply. Actually I am not getting your point properly. Do you mean to change my Internet Network? Can you please guide me in detail?

Comment: Did you upload the package at home or at work?If you did it in a company, could you upload your package with other network(not using the company's network)?

Comment: It works when I stop firewall thanks @DasiyTianMSFT It helps me a lot.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT I am now facing one major issue that I listed here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709264/how-to-solve-error-of-returned-exit-code-1-while-building-uwp-xamarin-based-ap) Can you please look into this?